# RXJS withlatestfrom behaving unexpectedly

Tags: rxjs

I am following an example in a tutorial ( https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/withlatestfrom.html ):

```
// RxJS v6+
import { withLatestFrom, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { interval } from 'rxjs';

//emit every 5s
const source = interval(5000);
//emit every 1s
const secondSource = interval(1000);
const example = source.pipe(
  withLatestFrom(secondSource),
  map(([first, second]) => {
    return `First Source (5s): ${first} Second Source (1s): ${second}`;
  })
);
/*
  "First Source (5s): 0 Second Source (1s): 4"
  "First Source (5s): 1 Second Source (1s): 9"
  "First Source (5s): 2 Second Source (1s): 14"
  ...
*/
const subscribe = example.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

When I run this code with RXJS 6.2.2, Node 8.9.4, I was expecting:

```
First Source (5s): 0 Second Source (1s): 4
First Source (5s): 1 Second Source (1s): 9
```

But I get:

```
First Source (5s): 0 Second Source (1s): 3
First Source (5s): 1 Second Source (1s): 8
```

Why is this?

Comment: The implementation uses `setInterval` so whether or not the timers will meet your expectation depends upon the guarantees offered by that API. What I can say is that `secondSource` is subscribed to first. I doubt there is a guarantee that the fifth invocation of the callback for the 1000 ms timer will be before the first invocation of the 5000 ms timer's callback - despite the 5000 ms `setInterval` call happening second.

Comment: yes it is really just a timing issue.  Logically both intervals will fire at the same time at the 5 second mark.  In practice they (a) cannot both fire at the same time in a single threaded environment and (b) timers are subject to jitter based upon system activity and are not guaranteed to fire at exactly the requested time.  Change your secondSource interval to something like `900` instead of `1000` and you'll probably see what you expected to see